# UI tests fail on Fastlane/CircleCI because no location is set on a fresh simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, circleci, fastlane

Currently our tests fail because when location permissions are granted, we never progress to the next screen because a location update never happens.

This is because a fresh simulator instance set up with Fastlane doesn't set a location. The app target scheme specifies a default location, and so does the UI testing target; neither are honoured. The locations DO get honoured when the tests are run from Xcode, just not when the simulator activates from the command line, because the simulator app never actually opens, just exists, owned by terminal but not visible. The location on the test suite is also set.

How can I set the location of the simulator in a script that will be honoured when the simulator runs in a non-visible way?

I've found this: https://github.com/lyft/set-simulator-location

It requires this script:

```
# download set-simulator-location
brew install lyft/formulae/set-simulator-location

# run simulator
export IOS_SIMULATOR_UDID=`instruments -s devices | grep "iPhone 6 (10.3) \[" | awk -F '[ ]' '{print $4}' | awk -F '[\[]' '{print $2}' | sed 's/.$//'`
echo $IOS_SIMULATOR_UDID
open -a "simulator" --args -CurrentDeviceUDID $IOS_SIMULATOR_UDID

# wait simulator to start fully
sleep 15

# set location
set-simulator-location -q London
```

But it seems clunky, and requires hard coding the specific simulator and then opening it, waiting 15 seconds, then setting the location on it. I feel like there must be a better way.

Comment: Hi, have you found a way to solve this?